# NextJS with NestJS Backend Set-Cookie header is ignored by browser

Tags: next.js, cookies, nestjs, fetch-api

I have a backend NestJS/Fastify app and a NextJS 13 frontend.

I use a client component to signin to my app, and in my devtools, I see the Set-Cookie header in the response.

```js
// backend auth route
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
@Post('sign-in')
async signIn(
  @Body() signInDto: SignInDto,
  @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: FastifyReply,
) {
  const { accessToken } = await this.authService.signIn(signInDto);

  response.setCookie('accessToken', accessToken);
}
```

Browser devtools:
[image]

The problem is that when I try to fetch other routes from my client components, using this kind of code:

```js
const url = new URL(
      '/api/v1/test',
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL ?? '',
    )
    fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error)
```

The cookies are not present in the request:
[image: not the cookie i expect!]

This is not the cookie I expect! By the way, `next-auth` is not installed in this project.

So, is there something I missed about cookies? Is it NextJS playing with cookies in my client components? How to make things so that my subsequent requests contain the cookie?

Thanks a lot